# sending automated reply through outlook with gpt model

Tags: python, imap, huggingface-transformers, gpt-2

I am trying to set an autopreply from my outlook, with gpt2 model. I use transformers library.
this is my code

```
import imaplib
import email
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Tokenizer
import smtplib
import getpass
import string

# Set up IMAP for Outlook email access
outlook_email = 'testingautoreply@outlook.com'
outlook_password = getpass.getpass(f'Enter the password for {outlook_email}:')
outlook_server = 'outlook.live.com'
outlook_mailbox = 'Inbox'

# Set up GPT-2 model
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained("gpt2")

def generate_response(input_text):
    input_ids = tokenizer.encode(input_text, return_tensors="pt", max_length=200, truncation=True)
    output = model.generate(input_ids, max_length=50, num_return_sequences=1, no_repeat_ngram_size=2)
    response = tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
    return response

def send_email(to, subject, message):
    from_email = outlook_email
    password = outlook_password

    msg = MIMEText(message)
    msg['To'] = to
    msg['From'] = from_email
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(outlook_server, 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(from_email, password)
        server.sendmail(from_email, to, msg.as_string())
        server.quit()
        print(f"Email sent to {to}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error sending email: {e}")

def sanitize_text(input_text):
    # Remove non-printable characters
    sanitized_text = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, input_text))
    return sanitized_text

def process_emails():
    # Connect to Outlook email
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(outlook_server)
    mail.login(outlook_email, outlook_password)
    mail.select(outlook_mailbox)

    # Search for unread emails
    result, data = mail.search(None, 'UNSEEN')
    email_ids = data[0].split()

    for email_id in email_ids:
        result, msg_data = mail.fetch(email_id, '(RFC822)')
        raw_email = msg_data[0][1]
        email_message = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email)
        
        # Extract email content
        sender = email_message['From']
        subject = email_message['Subject']
        body = email_message.get_payload()

        # Sanitize the email body
        sanitized_body = sanitize_text(body)

        # Generate a response using GPT-2
        response = generate_response(sanitized_body)

        # Send an automated reply
        send_email(sender, f"Re: {subject}", response)

    # Mark emails as read
    for email_id in email_ids:
        mail.store(email_id, '+FLAGS', '\Seen')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process_emails()
```

it sucessfully got into my outlook mail, but there is not email sent for the unread message. Anyone know why ?

I am expecting an email sent automatically if i run this code. I have tried to run it, sucessfuly got into the email but can not send a message to the unread one. I have tried also change the serve to outlook.live.com and outlook.microsoft365.com both doesnt work. my mail domain is outlook.live.com